# Can't scan but can print with Canon PIXMA MG5500

Tags: macos, scanning, canon

I have a Canon PIXMA MG5500 and a MacBook Pro with OS X 10.10.3

The printer and scanner are supposed to be wireless and I have no problems with the printer but when I try to use the scanner it just won't cooperate.

I have tried *everything*. I've uninstalled the drivers and reinstalled them, I've tried looking for answers in the manual and nothing.

When you want to scan something the scanner says I need to set my computer to scan. When I do that my computer can't find the scanner even though the connection is fine and sometimes it asks me to connect it with a USB cable which I don't have and it didn't follow the printer.

Comment: What app are you using to scan ? Did you try using the Image Capture app, already in your applications folder?

Comment: did you install the IJ Scan Utility2 , My Image Garden and Quick Menu...http://www.usa.canon.com/app/pdf/wireless/Setup_MG5520_Mac.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Scanning is definitely possible over WiFi using the Pixma iOS app for iPhone/iPad, I use it often this way. To scan wirelessly from a Mac you need to use the [Canon IJ Network Scanner Selector](http://ugp01.c-ij.com/ij/webmanual/ScanUtility/W/MG5500%20series/1.1/EN/SU/su-407.html) to install the scanner. Then you can scan using the Canon IJ Scan Utility 2 or any other scanning application. Note that the manual describes only the locations for Windows, but the utility is also there in Mac OS X if you installed the driver package or can be downloaded separately from the Canon website.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem with Canon Pixma E560, can print but can't scan. The solution I found was in firewall settings. Go to firewall options in security & privacy in system preferences. Allow incoming connections for all canon utilities.

Answer (score 1):

I was just having the same problem -   I can't just walk to my scanner and press "scan." I just keep getting  an error message saying "set the PC to start scanning."  Finally figured out I have to control my scanner through my computer! It's a simple solution. I'm on a Mac, so I hit the magnifying glass "search" in the upper right corner, started searching for  "Canon," and since I'd loaded the software previously,   "Canon IJ Scan Utility"  auto-filled in the search bar, along with a list of applications below the search bar. I double-clicked on the application that said "Canon IJ Scan Utility2" and my scanner options appeared. I wanted to scan a document, so I hit "document." The message "searching for scanners"  appeared, and my Canon started scanning immediately.
Of course, if "Canon IJ Scan Utility" doesn't auto-fill in your search bar, you may need to load the software driver. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The packaging for the Pixma printers is misleading. It's a wireless *printer*, but for scanning, you need to either tether to your computer, or plug a USB drive into the printer. When conducting the scan, you'll be prompted to choose the USB drive, and after scans are complete, you can walk the USB to your computer.

Comment: I disagree. It's both a wireless printer and scanner. I was able to do both quite successfully, up until I upgraded to El Capitan.

Comment: I disagree as well. Scanning over WiFi works if you use the Canon IJ Network Scanner Chooser and the Canon IJ Scan Utility 2, you can download both from the website.

Comment: I have a pixma 5500 and can confirm this answer is simply wrong. I was able to scan over wi-fi just fine after installing the driver for months. Now, suddenly, I can't select my pc anymore.

Comment: This answer does not help. It is possible to use this printer as a wireless scanner with macos. (as I understand it is impossible to connect by usb with a mac) You need to download the software from http://ij.start.canon
Unfortunately the info on Canons normal website is rubbish.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to scan from my Canon MG7500 scanner to my Mac with the pre-installed [Image Capture](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH17894?locale=en_US) program.  No need for any Canon software.

Good luck!

Comment: How is this useful?

Answer (score 0):

Reload your Pixma CD as though you were installing it for the first time. That worked for me.